# Using GavabDB for 3D face reconstruction from frontal image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, 3d

Project: 3D face reconstruction

Input: 2D frontal face Image Output: 3D face Reconstruction and expression simulation Platform: Matlab or Opencv cpp.

I found out after study that 3D Morphable Models (3DMM) algorithm is a good starting point for my project. But I don't have the Basel Face Model (3D face Database) to implement the algorithm. However, I have downloaded GavabDB from http://gavab.escet.urjc.es/recursos_en.html. Can I develop 3DMM using the GavabDB for 3D face reconstruction from frontal image? After reading the dataset description doc, I observed that Gavab doesn't provide Texture data of the 3D scans; is texture data compulsory?

Does the output quality depend on the 3D database used for modeling?

Comment: Removed my comment and the Matlab tag as this question is currently not yet related to matlab.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin ofcourse its related to matlab rit?

Comment: can anybody reply..